# I update my Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS using sudo apt update but have an error occurs

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, update-manager, repository

```
W: GPG error: http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease: Unknown error executing apt-key
E: The repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease: Unknown error executing apt-key
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease: Unknown error executing apt-key
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease: Unknown error executing apt-key
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease: Unknown error executing apt-key
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Please show `dpkg -l | grep ubuntu-keyring`